# Browser sync for Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, gulp

I'm using browser sync with an Angular SPA. Serving the site looks like this:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init(null, {
    server: {
      baseDir: './',
      middleware: [historyApiFallback()]
    }
  });
});
```

This works fine. The use of `historyApiFallback` (npm module) means browser sync doesn't freak out when going to a new URL path when all it needs to do is continue serving the `index.html`.

The problem I have is with watching files. I've tried this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', function() {
    runSequence('build-css', browserSync.reload);
  });
});
```

The watch task does work because the `build-css` task triggers fine. Then the console logs `Reloading Browsers...` and just hangs. The browser never gets the CSS injection or reload. What am I doing wrong here?

Note that I'm using `gulp-watch` not the native gulp watch purposely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server). It is a simple customized wrapper around BrowserSync to make it easy to serve SPAs(you don't even have to configure the history api).

You can use it by simple adding an entry in the `scripts` object in your `package.json` and running the following command: `npm run dev`.

`"scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
},`

The module will automatically watch for changes of your files and keep then sync. So it will work with your gulp, because it will update your browser after the `build-css` task is executed(because the output files will change).

I am currently using it with angular 1, angular 2 and vue.js and worked fine with all.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good and from a reputable source (John Papa). For the sake of usefulness to myself and others that might find this answer, would you be able to post a brief example of how that npm package would be executed in this situation?